# Why does \d* matches positions?

Tags: regex

Say I have the string '`this is an example`' and I try to match it against `/\d*/`, my assumption was that the entire string would match but the only match I received was positions (before the `t`, between the `t` and `h`, etc).

Why is this happening?

Comment: \d is for digit, so \d* is for digits or nothing. And nothing matches everywhere.

Comment: \d is digits. /\d*/ is numerous digits in a row.  I'm surprised you're getting any matches. /(\w+\s?)/ would at least match for each word.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx what do you mean by 'nothing matches everywhere'? 'Everywhere' means words too, right?

Comment: nothing is also known as "empty string" and there many in any string (length+1).

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx Can you provide some small example of a string and the empty strings in it? Thanks.

Comment: @daremarkovic - Is that not obvuious? "bar" = ("b" + "" + "ar) or ("bar" + "" + "r") or even ("bar" + "")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\d` means "any digit", `*` means "zero or more".

So in this case, it's matching every single position in the regex, because it's essentially "**match nothing**, or digits if there are some".

I'm not sure why you would think that `\d*` would match a string of non-digits...

Comment: How is 'nothing' defined in regex? Is 'nothing' basically word boundaries and positions between characters?

Comment: @daremarkovic 'nothing' is any position between characters. Word boundaries are special types of 'nothing' if you want.

Answer (score 0):

`\d` is a placeholder for digit (which could not be matched to letters). you either should use `\D` or you want to express something different at all.

Answer (score 0):

Because, in "this is an example"

- before "t" there are 0 or more digits
- between "t" and "h" there are 0 or more digits
- between "h" and "i" there are 0 or more digits

Got the picture?